# JQuery AJAX call returns JSONP but can't access JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to process the data that is returned in the JSONP request, but I've difficulties to make the call. Why does the following code fail?

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple JSONP Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Simple JSONP Test</div>
        <script>
            // alert('start');

            $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://www.myserver.com/simplejsontest.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                alert('Success! data: ' + data);
            },
            error: function (xr, msg, e) { alert('Msg: ' + msg + ', error: ' + e + 'xr: ' + xr.toString()); }
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the php file simplejsontest.php:

```
<?php

$myData = array(
//array(
    "id" => "1",
"Title" => "Dr.", 
"firstName" => "John", 
"lastName" => "King"); 
/*,
array(
    "id" => 2,
"Title" => "Dr.", 
"firstName" => "John", 
"lastName" => "King")
);
*/

//echo $_GET['callback']."(".'{"users":'.json_encode($myData).'})';
echo $_GET['callback']."(". json_encode($myData). ')';
?>
```

Comment: Please explain what “can't access JSON data” means; do you get an error message?

Comment: What is the value of the `$_GET['callback']`? Also, what is the result of the Ajax call? Success or error?

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` — You're making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the content-type of.

Comment: Define "not working". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and it ran without errors.

Comment: That was a good hint. I get a 404 error and researched further... I've made a little typo mistake (I've called simplejsontest.php, but the file actually is named simplejsonPtest).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose I should have been more specific.  I think the problem he's having is getting the data from the response to something he can use on his page.

I've tested this and it works.

I'm using "lastName" because that's an element in your $myData array in the PHP above.  Since you've used the variable "data" in your javascript you add the element "lastName" that you defined in your php array:

```
alert("last name: " + data.lastName);
```

If you want to return more than one result for each element in your object you'll use a multi-dimensional array and create some kind of counter when the response gets back to the javascript.

PHP:

```
$myData = array(
    "id" => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2
    ),
    "title" => array(
        0 => "Mr.",
        1 => "Dr."
    ),
    "firstName" => array(
        0 => "John",
        1 => "Sara"
    ),
    "lastName" => array(
        0 => "King",
        1 => "Jones"
    )
);

echo $_GET['callback']."(". json_encode($myData). ')';
```

This is the jquery/javascript to loop through the returned results.  For this example I'm just appending the last name to the body of the html:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var i = 0;
    do{
        $('body').append(data.lastName[i++]);

    }
    while(i < data.id.length);
},
```

Comment: It's JSONP. It gets "parsed" by loading the response as a `<script>`.

Comment: @Quentin I've edited my response to expand.  I think his alert is giving him something like [Object] and he doesn't know what to do with that.

Comment: Why do you suggest this data structure instead of

$myData = array(
array(
 "id" => "1",
"Title" => "Dr.", 
"firstName" => "John", 
"lastName" => "King"),
array(
 "id" => 2,
"Title" => "Dr.", 
"firstName" => "John", 
"lastName" => "King")
);

success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var i = 0;
    do{
        $('body').append(i + ">" + data[i++].lastName);
    }
    while(i < data.length);

Comment: There's no particular reason for that structure.  It's just the one I've used in the past.

Answer (score -1):

I think you must encode all the data with json_encode function. something like this:

```
json_encode($myData)
```

Or

```
json_encode($_GET['callback']."(". $myData. ')');
```

Comment: No. If you don't include `callback` then it isn't JSONP. If you encode the entire thing, you end up with a string, and it also isn't JSONP.